# Consuming oData Api in android application

Tags: android, retrofit, odata, sap-cloud-sdk

How do i consume oData services in an android application

1.can I use retrofit library and consume this oData services like how the Restful api's are usually consumed in android?i am trying to use this.

2.Should I use the apache olingo odata client for android

3.should I have to use the SAP cloud platform sdk for android

can someone tell me the pros and cons of these 3 approaches.Thank you!!

Comment: what i wanted to understand is..what difference does it make if i consume these oData API's using for eg: the retrofit library? or we should always stick to these oData libraries to consume for eg:apache olingo odata client or the SCP SDK for android.

Comment: this type of questions is not intended for SO, ask on Android dev forums

Comment: OData services are restful services and can be used using any http client like other restful APIs. However, the standards of odata will commit you to certain designs of requests and responses (this on the other hand gives you power/flexibility)  which is too much implementation and best used by an extra layer of client on top of any normal http client that handles this for you. This extra client could be [odata4j](http://odata4j.org/) or any other as suggested in the comments above.
If you're going to access few number of odata endpoints you may consume it like normal restful APIs.